# Suppress value-dump in Swift REPL

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

When using Swift REPL, every time I assign a value to a variable, it displays a whole dump of the value. I want to suppress this, because when it is an instance of a large struct, it completely blows out the previous lines.

```
  1 > let a = SomethingComplex()

a: SomethingComplex = {
  list = 3 values {
    [0] = {
      edges = 4 values {
        [0] = {
          id = 1
          from = 0x0000000100506110 {
            edges = 4 values {
              [0] = {
                id = 3
                from = 0x0000000100506a50 {
                  edges = 4 values {
                    [0] = {
                      id = 5
                      from = 0x0000000100506820 {...}
                      to = 0x0000000100506a50 {...}
                    }
  .
  .
  .
```

Is there a way to suppress this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift REPL runs in the context of the lldb debugger and, by default,
prints the values of variables declared in an expression.
This is controlled by the lldb variable

```
  print-decls                  -- If true, LLDB will print the values of
                                  variables declared in an expression.
                                  Currently only supported in the REPL
                                  (default: true).
```

(Use `:set list` in the Swift REPL to get a list of all lldb variables.)

So you can suppress at the output of variable declarations
by setting that variable to `false`. Example (note that a leading
colon is used to issue lldb commands):

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.39.1). Type :help for assistance.

  1> struct SomethingComplex { let x = 1; let y = 2 }
  2> let a = SomethingComplex()
a: SomethingComplex = {
  x = 1
  y = 2
}
  3> :set set print-decls false
  3> let b = SomethingComplex()
  4>
```